# One integral - two different results

Tags: integration

I have a problem with integrals substitution. Depending on the substitution I'm getting different results. Do I make mistake somewhere?

Following integral: $\int \frac{\cos x}{\sin^3x}dx$

$\sin x=t$

$\cos x\,dx=dt$

$dx= \frac{dt}{\cos x}$

I'am getting:

$\int \frac{\cos x}{\sin^3x}dx=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sin^2x}+C$

but if I substitute

$\cot x=t$

I'am getting:

$\int \frac{\cos x}{\sin^3x}dx=-\frac{1}{2}\cot^2x+C $

Comment: Welcome to Math SXBoth differ by a constant.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\sin^2{x}+\cos^2{x}=1$, dividing by $\sin^2{x}$ gives
$$ \csc^2{x} = 1 + \cot^2{x}. $$
Since the integral is indefinite, it is only determined up to an arbitrary constant, so the answers *are* the same when this is accounted for. Yet another reason to remember your $+C$s!

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$\cot^2x-\frac{1}{\sin^2x}=\frac{\cos^2 x-1}{\sin^2x}=-1$$
so the two primitives differ by a constant. What may we conclude?

Comment: $1=\frac{1}{sin^2x}-cot^2x$
Shouldn't it be equal 0 not 1 to say that both of the expressions are equal? I don't understand it

Comment: @A.D. When you integrate $f$ you are looking for a function $F$ (primitive of $f$) such that $F'=f$. So we could have two different primitives and all primitives differ by a constant (the derivative of a constant is 0). Both your results are correct! Verify them by taking the derivative.